# Install React-Admin package from specific branch or with open pull request

Tags: react-admin

I am having difficulties trying to install a development branch of React-Admin packages with NPM in an active project, specifically:

- ra-tree-ui-materialui
- ra-tree-core

To have the changes made in this PR https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/3379

Is there any way of doing this in a similar way to how you normally would put this in package.json ("username/repo#branch")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to install a local version of one of React Admin's package, because we use a mono-repository that contains all the packages.

I see two solutions to your needs.

**Install the alpha builds**

The core team had just published an alpha for the next version of React Admin. It's not stable yet, but you can try it by running :

```sh
npm install --save ra-tree-core@next
npm install --save ra-tree-ui-materialui@next
```

**Install a local version for development**

If you want to tweak the React Admin packages while you are using them, you can fork the whole repo and use symbolic links.

```sh
# On a separate folder
git clone git@github.com:marmelab/react-admin.git
cd react-admin
make install
make build
cd packages/ra-tree-core
npm link # This will make this package available for linking
```

And on your project, then run:

```
npm link ra-tree-core
```

This will create a symbolic link between your local `ra-tree-core` and your node_module folder.

I showed these examples with npm, but `yarn link` works too.